# Low free space on a SharePoint Content DB

Tags: sql-server, content-database, size

We have to upload up to 133 video files to a SharePoint 2016 Site but there is a very low free space in the content DB. There are multiple sites for the same content DB but only 1 site collection is having large data. Please let me know how to increase the SharePoint content db size.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options:

1. Add new SharePoint Content Database (in Central Admin), and move the big site collection to the new Content Database using [Move-SPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spsite?view=sharepoint-ps) PowerShell command.
2. "Very low free space in the content DB" may or may not be an issue. If there is auto-growth enabled on the Content DB on SQL Server, SQL Server will just increase the DB size when it meets the limit, so it is not an issue. It may be an issue if autogrowth is not enabled, then you will run into issues when DB size meets the limit and need to do step 1. or manually grow the DB size in SQL.

I'd perhaps do a combination of both steps, so migrate the one clearly bigger Site Collection to dedicated Content Database (will make things more clear, and DB management easier due to smaller DB sizes in general), and review the autogrowth settings on all Content DBs to ensure you know how they are configured and can plan accordingly.

Too small autogrowth (10% is too small if you start with a 1 MB DB, but it might be OK if you set it to an existing 100GB DB) will cause fragmented DB files, and too big autogrowth (like 100GB) may cause slowness when autogrowth fires.

Comment: Yes, we already have autogrowth enabled by 10 MB. So I think we will try to upload all the video files first and see if we get any error then we will either move the big site collection to the new Content Database or manually grow the DB size in SQL.

Comment: You will (and already do) have hugely fragmented content DB files with 10MB autogrowth. I recommend increasing it to x00 MB, and evaluating if it would be required to defragment DB files. Of course depending of your hard drive infra, fragmentation may not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Autogrowth for a sharepoint content db should be at least 512 MB. Otherwise you will get a fragmented (slow) content database. If you know already how much MB you plan to upload, then you should pre-provision the db size.
If you plan to move sites to another (new created) content db, you should move the small ones, and leave the big one in the existing content db. Site collection backup, restore and move operations are not recommended for site bigger then 100GB. A content DB in a general scenario should not exceed the size of 200GB. Sitecollections bigger than 100 GB should have it's own content db.